# Copying file and write the info of file backwards

Tags: c

Need create a copy of the file that was previously created with fifteen random numbers inside, and in this copy write those numbers backwards.

I tried to read the file with for() and write to the array, which will also fill in the newly created file with for(), but the IDE stops the script as soon as it goes to for().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
char a[20], sf[20], tf[20];
FILE *source, *target;
int i;

printf("Enter name of file to copy\n");
gets(sf);

source = fopen(sf, "r");

if (source == NULL){
    printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Enter name of target file\n");
gets(tf);

target = fopen(tf, "w");

if (target == NULL){
    fclose(source);
    printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
    exit(1);
}

for(i=0;i<15;i++){
    fscanf(source, "%d", a[i]);
    //printf("%d\n", a[i]);
}
for(i=15;i>0;i--){
    fprintf(target, "%d\n", a[i]);
}

//printf("File copied successfully.\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the IDE stops the script"? Does it give you an error message? Also, that second for-loop should run from 14 to 0 (your loop will make it run from 15 to 1), and use of `gets()` is strongly discouraged because there's no check that the filename the user types in will actually fit in the buffer you've given it.

Comment: Is there any error message provided by the IDE? Are you certain it's exiting at the beginning of the for loop and not failing to open the target files?

Comment: Not an answer to your solution, but as far as reversing something goes, the first thing I would do is find a C implementation of a stack and just use that. Whenever somebody says "reverse something" I pretty much immediately think stacks.

Comment: you already accept my answer but I added a proposal if that interest you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some remarks :

- as it is said in remark you read *int* so you need an array of *int*, not an array of *char* to save them, currently you will write out of *a* with an undefined behavior
- if you need to save 15 values an array for 15 is enough, 20 (supposing *int*) is useless
- *never* use *gets*, it is deprecated (since years) because dangerous, use *fgets* to not take the risk to write out of the receiving string, and do not forget to remove the probable newline
- may be the input and output files will be the same, so read first before to open output file and write its contents
- `fscanf(source, "%d", a[i]);` is invalid and must be `fscanf(source, "%d", &a[i]);`
- check the result of *fscanf* to manage error cases in the input file
- `fprintf(target, "%d\n", a[i]);` must be `fprintf(target, "%d\n", a[i-1]);`
- to explicitly *fclose* the output file is better in case you later transform your program to something more complex

---

A proposal :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 15

FILE * openIt(const char * msg, const char * dir)
{
  char fn[256];

  printf(msg);

  if (fgets(fn, sizeof(fn), stdin) == NULL)
    /* EOF */
    return NULL;

  char * p = strchr(fn, '\n');

  if (p != NULL)
    *p = 0;

  FILE * fp = fopen(fn, dir);

  if (fp == NULL)
    fprintf(stderr, "cannot open '%s'\n", fn);

  return fp;
}

int main()
{
  FILE * fp;

  if ((fp = openIt("Enter name of file to copy\n", "r")) == NULL)
    return -1;

  int a[N], i;

  for (i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
    if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &a[i]) != 1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "invalid integer rank %d\n", i);
      fclose(fp);
      return -1;
    }
  }

  fclose(fp);

  if ((fp = openIt("Enter name of target file\n", "w")) == NULL)
    return -1;

  while (i--) {
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", a[i]);
  }

  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra r.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat in
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12
13
14
15
not read
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter name of file to copy
in
Enter name of target file
out
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat out
15
14
13
12
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter name of file to copy
out
Enter name of target file
out
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat out
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, i forgot write "&" into fscanf.

Comment: @Dante, yes and also `fprintf(target, "%d\n", a[i]);` must be `fprintf(target, "%d\n", a[i-1]);` etc, I edited my answer to put a proposal